# I believe this is a quoting and a variable scoping question

Tags: bash, variable

The following is a recommended solution.  I ran it and it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

function exit_handler() {
  local device_name="${1}"
  echo "Exit handler: ${device_name}"
}

function other() {
  echo "Other: ${device_name}"
}

function do_something() {
  local device_name="abc"
  trap "exit_handler '${device_name}'" EXIT
  other
}

do_something

# (my comment) I am assuming an implied exit here
```

I actually entered a real exit into the terminal at the command line where the comment was added

What do I not understand and why does it work given the following questions:

Question one -- given:

```
    trap "exit_handler '${device_name}'" EXIT
```

The single quotes around ${device_name} indicate (to me anyway that) substitution should occur when the trap is initiated (after exit is processed which will be after 'do_something' returns and local variable ${device_name} no longer exists it appears to me)  since there is no exit statement in the code and no noticeable cause for an error to cause an exit.  Function 'do_something' should have returned and there should no longer exist a variable ${device_name} to satisfy the substitution.  If the statement were recoded without the single quotes as

```
    trap "exit_handler ${device_name}" EXIT
```

I clearly see how the substitution can occur when the trap statement is executed long before an exit occurs.  What do I not understand about bash quoting here?

Question Two -- given the following statement in 'do_something':

```
    other
```

Is there some special scoping rule that allows the local value of ${device_name} to be available to a function 'other' called from 'do_something' when it is supposedly local to 'do-nothing' and 'other' is clearly NOT local to 'do-something'?  Other languages scoping rules I believe would prevent this.  Requiring the function call like the trap call to need ${device_name} as an argument as follows

```
    other "${device_name}"
```

and 'other' would require the assignment of the argument to a local variable

```
  local device_name="${1}"
```

Apparently there is something about scoping in Bash I do not understand.

Comment: "I believe this is a quoting and a variable scoping question" -- then just write it as a question?!

Comment: Wait what, this is two unrelated questions in one?

Comment: I will concede I should probably split it into two, my mistake.  Actually the relationship I saw between these questions is that this is someone else's preferred solution I have tested and found to work and and am laboring to understand WHY it works to learn about BASH. So I can better code and debug bash scripts.  You may not believe it but I learned considerably more than I expected about BASH, especially when it comes to variable scoping, what I learned was both surprising and significant in terms of coding and debugging in BASH.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute this code,

> ```
> local device_name="abc"
> trap "exit_handler '${device_name}'" EXIT
> ```

The shell sees the double quotes and evaluates variables and `$()` expressions within it:

```
device_name="abc"
trap "exit_handler 'abc'" EXIT
```

The shell then executes the result, which sets up an exit trap. When (if) the trap fires, the function `exit_handler` will be called with a single three character parameter `abc`.

Your statement, "*The single quotes around ${device_name} indicate (to me anyway that) substitution should occur when the trap is initiated*" is incorrect. The double quotes around the entire expression control what the shell sees and evaluates. The single quotes inside the string are simply ordinary characters at this point.

If you want deferred evaluation of `$device_name` the trap argument will need to be passed in single quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash

exit_handler() {
    local device_name="$1"
    echo "Exit handler: $device_name"
}

other() {
    echo "Other: $device_name"
}

do_something() {
    local device_name="abc"
    trap 'exit_handler "$device_name"' EXIT
    other
}

do_something
```

Comment: I write trap statements like you did my problem is not with your syntax at all, I prefer it.  My problem comprehending what is happening as stated above is the timing problem between the destruction of the local variable and the attempt to use it when the exit trap is initiated. First Do_something returns as part of that ${device_name} should be destroyed then exit starts, then exit completes, then the trap is initiated and $(device_name) that I believe is destroyed somehow for reasons I do not understand is around to perform the substitution.

Comment: @pasha19 I've added a little more explanation. Your understanding of `"text '$variable' text"` is flawed and I've tried to explain more clearly what's happening in this situation

Comment: AH -- yes I see what you are saying what would be required for my interpretation would be "exit_handler "'${device_name}' a double quoted string concatenated to a single quoted string.  In essence the single quotes inside the double quotes cause the prototype command probably to be "exit_handler 'abc'".  Meaning this was NOT delayed substitution -- I now understand that part.

Comment: @pasha19 You can get a better idea what's happening as your script runs by putting `set -x` at the beginning; this makes it print each command after things like variable and command substitutions have been done, but before the command itself is actually executed (although sometimes it displays commands using unexpected quoting modes -- in your original script it would've printed `+ trap 'exit_handler '\''abc'\''' EXIT`, which *equivalent* to `trap "exit_handler 'abc'" EXIT`, just weirdly written).

Comment: Or your syntax that I prefer 'exit_handler "${device_name}"' and I use.  The problem is that I do not use the syntax I found and misinterpreted its meaning.

Comment: Gordon -- yes I should have, thank you.

Comment: @pasha19 why do you keep using braces (`${var}`)? They're mostly unnecessary (`$var`)

Comment: @pasha19 you say you'd want to use "_a double quoted string concatenated to a single quoted string_". That would be wrong, because you'd lose the deferred quotes around the deferred variable expansion. Stick with my suggested answer and protect the variable and its value when it's used

Comment: I agree whole heartedly concerning the string construct.  I was attempting to understand someone else's code written to their standards and not mine.  You get better at coding in my experience when you can understand the code of another.  I realize the braces are redundant, but in the code I can currently writing for my purposes I have an abundance of array references that require braces.  Being relatively new to BASH, I was tending to leave those out.  So I, personally, am now prone to including braces where they are not needed to avoid leaving them out when they are needed.

Comment: Many of the variables that could do with out braces are actually references to [0] elements of an array where I should probably not be taking advantage of the shorthand and actually should explicitly include the [0].